# C# Enumeration Parse and Reflection

Tags: c#, enums

I have an enumeration defined as follows:

```
public enum Format {
  Normal = 1,
  Type2 = 2,
  Type3 = 3
}
```

I'm trying to use Reflection and calling a dynamic type-casting function.  However in the code below, the value of "value" is "3" and not "Type3", and it is not be recognized as an enum.  Is it possible to use the int value, 3 to recognize the enumeration?

```
Type enumType = property.PropertyType;
if (Enum.IsDefined(enumType, value))
   return Enum.Parse(enumType, value);
```

Comment: What _exactly_ is `value`? What does it come from?

Comment: The value comes from the Database.  The value is a Db String value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call `Enum.ToObject()` to convert the raw value to a boxed instance of the enum.

Comment: @GW Just to clarify in the context of the question, you would want to call `Enum.ToObject(enumType, value)`.

Comment: Thanks! I'm going to try it out now

Comment: Great it looks like it is working.  However, I had to convert the value to an integer type in order for Enum.ToObject.  Do you have any recommendations of what would be the best way to handle enum-string value if that was to come in instead? ( Like if Normal or Type2 were to come in - so to be able to handle both an int and a string)

Comment: @GW: Call `int.TryParse`, and call `Enum.Parse` if that returns false.